# How to fix select_all returning only one result instead of multiple results

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

My code can be boiled down to the following:

```
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let endpoints = vec!['http://google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://example.com'];
let futures: Vec<_> = endpoints.iter().map(|endpoint| {
            return client
                .get(endpoint)).send();
}).collect();

let (item_resolved, _remaining_futures, _last) = select_all(futures).await;
let mut responses = vec![];

for item in item_resolved {
    responses.push(item.json::<ResponseStruct>().await);
}

dbg!(responses);
```

problem is responses only contain one result. I expect it to be a vec of results from calling the endpoints.

Comment: `select_all()` gives the first result. Maybe you want [`join_all()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html)?

Comment: damn! I thought if `select_ok` gives the first result, then `select_all` should get ALL the results!

Comment: Nope, `select_all()` gives the first result, `select_ok()` gives the first _successful_ result. `select()` gives the first result of only two futures.

Comment: If you want all successful results, try [`try_join_all()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.try_join_all.html).

Comment: I think I want a join_all but with the ability to know which endpoints resulted in an error.

Comment: So you just need to check?

Comment: I guess. I am not just sure how to link back the results to the corresponding endpoint because I do not think the result is guaranteed to be in the same order as the endpoints in the collections. And this is needed for error reporting for instance. To know which of the endpoints actually failed

Comment: You can attach this information to the future.

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that? In my case I am using `reqwest` to make the `http` call. I am not sure where to attach extra information to the `Future`

Comment: `async { (fut.await, url) }`.

Comment: sorry if this is a noob response. But that does not work. I start with `let futures: Vec<_> = endpoints.iter().map(|endpoint| { reqwest.send(endpoint)})` which gives me a collection of Futures, and then I do `let raw_responses = join_all(futures).await;`. I am not sure where I can attach the info about the endpoint to the future

Comment: Instead of `map(|endpoint| { reqwest.send(endpoint)})` do `map(|endpoint| async { (reqwest.send(endpoint).await, url) })` and then each response is a tuple of `(response, url)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) from the `futures` crate.

Here's an example I just shared from another answer: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f2faf54cec2267b7c6b0839439dea0d